# how can I change the name of my image when uploading it to the cloudinary server?

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

I am trying to change the name of an image that comes in base64, to a name that I will define later. how can I do it? I want to customize the names in the cloudinary server

```
  var uploadOptions = {
    params : {
      //'upload_preset': "YOUR_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PRESET",
      'upload_preset': "xxx",
    }

//imageURI is base64 image
//.upload("YOUR_IMAGE_UPLOAD_LINK", imageURI, uploadOptions)
  .upload("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/xxxx/image/upload", imageURI, uploadOptions)

    .then(function(result) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming the image is done using the `public_id` parameter, for example:

```
var uploadOptions = {
    params : {
      //'upload_preset': "YOUR_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PRESET",
      'upload_preset': "xxx",
      'public_id': "imageName"
    }
```

It can also contain folders. For example:

```
'public_id': "myfolder/imagename"
```

Or

```
'public_id': "imagename"
'folder': "myfolder"
```

You can read more about it [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload).

Comment: great! It works, but when I try to take a new photo with the same name (public_id), it is not replaced, the first one remains. how can I do it? thanks!

Comment: For security purposes, Cloudinary doesn't allow overwriting resources on its unsigned uploads feature. To overwrite, you'll have to use signed uploads (using a signature). For more information - https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/208335975-How-safe-secure-is-it-to-use-unsigned-upload-from-web-browsers-or-mobile-clients-